# Upgrade from .net Core 2.0 to 2.2.5 on Unix

Tags: asp.net-core

My website, hosted at DigitalOcean, is currently running on .net core 2.0, but I want to upgrade to .net core 2.2.5

As I understand it I have two options:

1.) Keep .net core 2.0 and install .net core 2.2.5 alongside.

2.) Uninstall .net core 2.0 using the script [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/release/2.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh). And then install .net Core 2.2.5

If I do option 1.) I understand this will affect diskspace used on droplet, but what about website performance, are there any performance issues or other issues doing this option?

Comment: Performance issue depends upon your website code rather than framework. Try benchmarking for more elaborate results if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install multiple dotnet core runtimes side by side. This will not affect performance of your app. As a default, your app will use the runtime with the highest version number.